# Every time I try to download discord.py it doesnt work

Tags: python

I write

```
pip install discord.py
```

it says

```
File "<stadin>", line 1
pip install discord.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I try to wirte

```
$ pip install discord.py
```

it was the same problem

I try to write

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

It was the same problem. I need your help, guys

Comment: What is your python version? According to PyPi `Python 3.8 or higher is required`.

Comment: Also add information about your Operating System and Python version in your question statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't write `pip install discord` in a file / in the python REPL, you type this into a terminal or command prompt itself, to tell python to install discord. If your on linux/mac, open a terminal, on windows, open `cmd` or powershell, and run:

```bash
python -m pip install discord.py
```

What you did previously was type `python`, which dropped you into a Python interpreter (python REPL), and you typed `pip install discord.py`, as if it were python code (its not, its a terminal command).

Answer (score -1):

You should enter the python mode first and enter `pip install discord.py`this is not advisable。
You should execute it directly under the cmd window, it will work normally。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwC54.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I did not face a problem to install discord.py. I tested with `Python 3.10.0` and `pip 22.3.1`

```
pip install discord.py
Collecting discord.py
  Downloading discord.py-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4
  Downloading aiohttp-3.8.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (358 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 358.3/358.3 kB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /Volumes/SP PHD U3/python/venvs/tempPrj/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (22.2.0)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Downloading yarl-1.8.2-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.0/61.0 kB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
  Downloading async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
  Downloading aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Downloading multidict-6.0.4-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (29 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in /Volumes/SP PHD U3/python/venvs/tempPrj/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (2.1.1)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
  Downloading frozenlist-1.3.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (35 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /Volumes/SP PHD U3/python/venvs/tempPrj/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py) (3.4)
Installing collected packages: multidict, frozenlist, async-timeout, yarl, aiosignal, aiohttp, discord.py
Successfully installed aiohttp-3.8.3 aiosignal-1.3.1 async-timeout-4.0.2 discord.py-2.1.0 frozenlist-1.3.3 multidict-6.0.4 yarl-1.8.2
```

Answer (score -2):

As per [discord.py package on PyPi server](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/):

> Required Python >=3.8.0

You can check your Python version using:

```
python --version
```

Or if that doesn't work

```
python3 --version
```

If version is `3.7 or less`, then you should update your Python installation to `3.8 or above` and try again **running pip command on terminal**.

```
pip install discord.py
```